# Simulating page lifecycle in code

Tags: .net, webforms, page-lifecycle

I have a custom `Control` on which I override the `OnInit` method.

**Update**

It seems I need to get the `Init` event through `userControl.GetType().GetEvent("Init")`. However the `RaiseMethod` property of the event is `null` so I'm unable to *raise* the event through reflection. **Any leads?**

## Old

I use the following code to load the control (`ReflectionUtil` invokes the method using reflection):

```
        Page p = new Page();
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)p.LoadControl(path);
        p.Controls.Add((Control)userControl);

        //EventArgs eventArgs = new EventArgs();

        //ReflectionUtil.CallMethod((object)p, "OnInit", (object[])new EventArgs[1] { eventArgs });
        //ReflectionUtil.CallMethod((object)userControl, "OnInit", (object[])new EventArgs[1] { eventArgs });

        //Plain Reflection doesn't work either...
        EventArgs eventArgs = new EventArgs();

        MethodInfo initMethod = userControl.GetType().GetMethod("OnInit");
        initMethod.Invoke(userControl, (object[])new EventArgs[1]
          {
            eventArgs
          });
```

However when I set a breakpoint in my custom control's `OnInit` method it does not get invoked. **Am I missing something here?** Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the error in the ReflectionUtil code? Does it work in other situations?

Comment: Plain old reflection doesn't work either... However it cannot find the `OnInit` method nor the `Init` method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OnInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.oninit.aspx) is protected and [GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) overload you are using only gets public methods.

You could use [the overload with the bindingflag NonPublic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx) to get the protected method.

Comment: `userControl.GetType().GetMethod("OnInit", BindingFlags.NonPublic)` this also returns `null`?

Comment: You might need to combine the flags like this: `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic`

Comment: It still returns `null`. Could it be that `Init` is actually an event and that it needs to be invoked differently?

Comment: Init is an event. OnInit is the method that will raise it in its base implementation.

Comment: I've taken the `OnInit` method now through normal reflection and I get to invoke it, however my overriden `OnInit` method does not get called... No exceptions either...

Comment: Did you call it on an instance of UserControl or on an instance of the specific UserControl?

Comment: I called it on the instance yes. Problem was I was using ScriptMethods which are not tied to any lifecycle (or it might be executed already). Solution was to use the `ServerUtility.Execute` method on a newly created Page instance. This invokes the entire lifecycle.